# Network profile's activity "posts" subtab is showing "no activity found"

Tags: bug, profile-page, recent-activity

If you go to [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) and click your user name listed at the top of the site, you'll see your profile.

From there click `'activity'` → `'posts'`.

Mine shows:

> *no activity found*

If you click on 'all', clearly I have recent activity, including 'posts'. Something seems to be amiss.

Comment: Same issue for my profile. The 'comments', 'accepts', 'reviews' and 'badges' sections are also wrongly showing *no activity found*. 'all' and 'revisions' are ok.

Comment: This is working fine for me.  There is a long list of activity posting.

Comment: "If you click on 'all', clearly I have recent activity, including 'posts'." It happens exactly the opposite to me: individual tabs works, all doesn't :(

Comment: @braiam Today I am seeing the same thing. Every tab works except the 'all' tab.

Comment: There's also a considerable server lag.